# Trigger silverlight datagrid to resize

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a situation where I'm using a datagrid to display two different sets of columns based on the data being displayed.  I hide/display the columns based on the data and one type has more columns displayed.  An example of the type of setup I have is:

> Type1 columns: Name, DOB, Address,
>   Height, Weight, Occupation, Years
>   Experience.
>
> Type2 columns: Name, DOB, Address,
>   Height, Occupation, Marital Status,
>   Hair Color, Eye Color, Ethnicity.
>
> My dataGrid columns are the union of
>   these two sets.

When I display Type1, I get seven columns of equal width.  When I switch to Type2, I set Weight and Years Experience to collapsed and set Marital Status, Hair Color, Eye Color, and Ethnicity to visible.  The first 3 columns retain their width and the last 6 columns get scrunched down to fit.  Does anyone know how to trigger a resize of all the columns?

Edit:  I'm using Width="*" for all columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UpdateLayout gets called on it's own when you change something.  I found if I initially display it in it's entirety (all columns) then It diplays properly. You can do this for a split second and the user will never see it.

Answer (score 0):

Call [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout%28VS.95%29.aspx) on the Grid